# Difference in performance between iOS devices

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, performance

I'm developing a game for ios and notice surprising results performance-wise between my devices.

for example, my iphone 5 will perform better than my ipad mini retina.  I really have no point of reference on how the two should compare.  If they shared similar processor speeds, it would make sense that the ipad might suffer a performance problem since the textures are twice as big.. but I'm just guessing here.

When I look up processor speeds etc, I seem to find very general information (A6, or A7 processor).  I'm looking for some easily understandable performance comparisons between devices so that I can predict which devices would perform better.

Comment: Geekbench results: http://browser.primatelabs.com/ios-benchmarks  Your mileage will vary.

Comment: If your game is graphics intensive the larger screen of the mini would have an impact on performance.

Comment: I figured. I thought the Minis processing power compared to an iPhone would make up for that though